# How do i make the dots the land in the triangle change color

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

This is my code, it draws a triangle using turtle, and then generate 300 random dots, my question is how do i make the dots that land INSIDE the triangle change color for example blue and the dots outside the triangle remain black? could someone add onto my code please? Thanks in advance.

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint
speed("fastest")

area_size = 800 
max_coord = area_size / 2
num_dots = 300 
setup(area_size, area_size)

penup()
goto(-200, -200)
pendown()
goto(200, -200)
goto(200, 200)
goto(-200,-200)

for _ in range(num_dots):

    dots_pos_x = randint(-max_coord, max_coord)
    dots_pos_y = randint(-max_coord, max_coord)

    penup()
    goto(dots_pos_x, dots_pos_y)
    dot(7)
    pendown()

hideturtle()
done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before your call to `dot`, add this code:

```
if -200 < dots_pos_y < dots_pos_x < 200:
    pencolor('blue')
else:
    pencolor('black')
```

The `if` statement does a test to see if the random coordinates you've chosen for the dot fall inside the triangle or not. Python's comparison operator chaining makes this really compact! A more explicit version of the test would be:

```
(dots_pos_y > -200 and      # above bottom edge of the triangle
 dots_pos_x < 200 and       # to the left of the right edge
 dots_pos_x > dots_pos_y)   # to the lower-right of the diagonal edge
```

In Python a chained comparison expression like `A < B < C` is equivalent to `A < B and B < C`, so the two versions work out the same (if you rearrange them a bit).